# Would a charged point particle (or a collection of equally-charged point particles) "feel" electromagnetic acceleration?

Tags: electromagnetism, acceleration, equivalence-principle

The Equivalence Principle says that free fall is an inertial reference frame, and that you can't distinguish gravity from being in an accelerated reference frame.
One of the ways I understood this is that, because of warped spacetime (metric tensor isn't Minkowski anymore), the proper acceleration (the magnitude of the 4-acceleration) in free-fall is zero. And since the proper acceleration is the acceleration that is "felt" by an object/accelerometer as it's accelerating, it makes sense that it would be zero when your situation is indistinguishable from "having no acceleration and being in an inertial frame".

However, think about a charged point particle in a uniform electric field. Or perhaps a group of charged point particles, all with the exact same mass-to-charge ratio. The proper acceleration isn't zero, it's qE/M. And yet, an accelerometer made up of only particles with the same mass-to-charge ratio wouldn't read anything, because all its constituents would accelerate at the same rate.

Does this mean that proper acceleration isn't always reflective of what acceleration is "felt" by a system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And yet, an accelerometer made up of only particles with the same mass-to-charge ratio wouldn't read anything, because all its constituents would accelerate at the same rate.

> Does this mean that proper acceleration isn't always reflective of what acceleration is "felt" by a system?

In Newtonian mechanics this indeed would be true: it is impossible to detect the presence of a uniform field producing the same force per unit mass in all bodies.

However, if we have several charged particles with different velocities comparable with the speed of light, we would notice that they accelerate in a uniform electric field differently. So, special relativity provides us with varying *effective* charge to mass ratio, which would allow one to deduce the presence of uniform electric field.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, and after some wrangling I figured out how to math that effect out.
However, there's still one question I have left, and it's about proper acceleration. If the particles were at rest relative to each other, then they would all accelerate at the same rate... and yet the proper acceleration of the system wouldn't be zero. That feels weird and I can't figure out what the problem here is.

Answer (score 0):

> The proper acceleration isn't zero, it's qE/M. And yet, an accelerometer made up of only particles with the same mass-to-charge ratio wouldn't read anything, because all its constituents would accelerate at the same rate.

All of the charged particles would move the same way which can't reveal their acceleration in their rest frame only if they started with the same velocity and weren't interacting with each other.

In reality because they are accelerated in a frame where Maxwell's equations hold, they will produce EM forces on each other which will affect their motion and this changed motion will reveal they are under action of external field even based on positions and velocities of the particles in the rest frame of the system.

Comment: A collection of charged particles will experience a "self-induction" effect.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming they're test particles with charge small enough that they don't affect each other, similar to how the einstein equivalence principle gets messy when your test masses start attracting each other.

Comment: @EricVilas they affect each other proportionally to charges. But charges can't be zero, so there is always some interaction. But let's say we ignore that, then there is still difference in acceleration of the different particles due to their different velocities (see A.V.S.'s answer).

Comment: Even a single charge will radiate and will be "accelerated less" than a non-radiating charge.